# Create custom rule java with for sonar analyse

Tags: java, plugins, sonarqube

i always used xpath to create custom rule in sonar, but now xpath is removed from plugin java, i need help for my first custom rule in java :

If there is a `@Stateless` or `@Stateful` annotation on a class, there should be a `@Interceptors` annotation. If it's not the case, it should be a Critical issue.

i followed this step : 
Create a standard SonarQube plugin.
Put a dependency on the jar of the language plugin for which you are writing custom rules.
Create as many custom rules as required
Generate the SonarQube plugin (jar file).
Place this jar file in the `SONARQUBE_HOME/extensions/plugins` directory.
Restart the SonarQube server.

and i'm able to follow all the steps but to create custom rule i need to know what i can put on the java class to define my rule before generate the sonarqube plugin.

can anyone help me, thanks in advance!

Regards,
Youssef

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you need to get the annotations of a class. We've done this for `@VisibleForTesting` in a custom plugin.

Look in https://github.com/arxes-tolina/sonar-plugins/tree/master/src/main/java/de/tolina/sonar/plugins/vft/checks package, especially `HasVisibleForTesting.java` and `IsVisibleForTesting.java`.

Comment: thank you very much Frank, it's kind of you, but i'm using version 4.5.1 of SQ and 2.9.1 of java plugin, if you have an example of custom rule was worked with my version that will be very great.

Comment: Sorry Youssef, no 4.5.1 for us and no chance / time for me to check this, but good luck!

Comment: i created a new project that can generate a custom java rule plugin for sonar 4.5.1, it's working fine, il post it on git ;)